# Why won't a label show up in a JFrame GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, swingworker

I'm getting started in JFrame, but I've followed the tutorial I'm using almost to the letter. I can change the dimensions and background color of the window, but I can't add a label or anything.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Game");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(800,600);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        window.add(label);
        label.setVisible(true);
        label.setText("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did actually add the label, but you made your `JFrame` window visible via `window.setVisible(true)` before adding all the components. Therefore the frame was rendered without the label. So what you should do is the following:

- Call `setVisible(true)` on the `JFrame` after all components were added. Best thing to do is to make it the last call when building your GUI components.
- There is no need to call `setVisible(true)` on the `JLabel`. As the label is then part of the frame, it will be rendered automatically.
- Please don't use `null` layout. Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). So using fixed sizes is not the way to go with swing.
- You may read through the [Oracle Java Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) for getting to know everything. You will also find many working examples there along the way.

After fixing your snippet, it would look like this:

```
public class Game{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Game");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        window.add(label);
        label.setText("Hello World");
        // this will cause the window to be sized 
        // according to the preferred size of its components inside
        window.pack(); 
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a `visible property` at earlier than creating a `label`. Sequence of initiating object is in inconsistent. It should be like this.

```
Frame window = new JFrame("Game");
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setSize(800,600);
---
---
---
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
---
--
 window.setVisible(true);
```